# How to define a Django model with a reference to itself?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.5

I'm new to Django and currently write an application, where users can enter their opinions on some topic.

Every opinion A may have zero or more opinions, which support A and several (zero or more) opinions, which refute A.

I tried to create a model for this and wrote a `models.py` file like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Opinion(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    proArguments = models.ManyToManyField(Opinion, verbose_name="Pro arguments")
    contraArguments = models.ManyToManyField(Opinion, verbose_name="Contra arguments")
```

When I run `python manage sqlall`, I get following error:

```
  File "D:\dev\history-site\history_site\opinions\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Opinion(models.Model):
  File "D:\dev\history-site\history_site\opinions\models.py", line 8, in Opinion
    proArguments = models.ManyToManyField(Opinion, verbose_name="Pro arguments")

NameError: name 'Opinion' is not defined
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [docs of `ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-manytomany):

> Requires a positional argument: the class to which the model is related. This works exactly the same as it does for `ForeignKey`, including all the options regarding recursive and lazy relationships.

Which [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> To create a recursive relationship -- an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself -- use `models.ForeignKey('self')`.

So:

```
proArguments = models.ManyToManyField("self", verbose_name="Pro arguments")
contraArguments = models.ManyToManyField("self", verbose_name="Contra arguments")
```

I'm slightly wondering about your data model if arguments are considered opinions as well, but that's another matter.

Comment: I argue that arguments are opinions, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: As that argument is your opinion, I would argue that I'm of the opinion that it's clearly not an argument. But let's not have this argument because it gets very opinionated.

Comment: @Thomas Is there a way to tell Django that there may be opinions without arguments (when both collections are empty) ? I modified field defintion to `proArguments = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Pro arguments", related_name='proargs', null='true', blank='true')`, but when I create a new instance of `Opinion` in the admin, there is one pro argument and one contra argument (even though, I didn't enter them).

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use self. And since, you have two m2m self relationship you need to add a related_name argument or provide symmetrical=False

```
class Opinion(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    proArguments = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Pro arguments", related_name='my_proargs')
    contraArguments = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Contra arguments", related_name='my_contraarg')
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to use 'self'

```
proArguments = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Pro arguments")
contraArguments = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Contra arguments")
```

From django documentation:

> To create a recursive relationship -- an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself -- use models.ForeignKey('self').